# Background-color of a div fitting to content, rather than borders, due to margin collapsing?

Tags: html, block, background-color, css

I have a div under a form which I want to stick to the form. I wish to know why when the div has display block the background does not fill up to the border of the div(with background-color) but fits around the content. margin 0, padding 0.
I found 2 solutions which bothers me and I do not understand: If I add visible border to the div, the background fills all the way to the form. If I change display attribute of the div to inline-block the div background fill to the top. What I am asking is why this happens and maybe a better way to fix it. I am beginner to CSS, thanks.

```
    _______________________
    |      form            |
    |______________________|
     ----------------------- border of div sticking to form as wanted

  unwanted white space between border and content due to color not showing

    _______________________
    |     div content      |       
    |                      |
    |______________________|

     div{
         background-color: #3B3B3B;
         width:652px;
         margin:0;
         padding:0;
         display:block;
        }
    .formStyle {
               width: 652px;
               height: 64px;
               background: linear-gradient(-15deg, transparent 0%, #3b3b3b 80%), linear-gradient(15deg, transparent 0%, #3b3b3b 80%), linear-gradient(to bottom, #3b3b3b 70%, #000000 90%);
               margin:0;
               }
```

HTML as requested:

```
            <form action="" class="formStyle">
                <img class="computerImage">
                <label>members login:</label>
                <input name="Your name" type="text" id="yourname" value="Your name">
                <input name="emailid" type="text" id="emailid" value="Email Id">
                <input name="" type="submit" class="button" value="GO">
            </form>
            <div>
                <h2>about total management?</h2>

                <p>Total Management is a free, tableless, W3C-compliant web design layout by Template World. This template has been
                    tested and proven compatible with all major browser environments and operating systems. You are free to modify
                    the design to suit your tastes in any way you like.</p>

                <p>We only ask you to not remove <span>"Design by Template World"</span> and the link http://www.templateworld.com
                    from the footer of the template.</p>

                <p class="lasttext">If you are interested in seeing more of our free web template designs feel free to visit our
                    website, Template World. We intend to add at least 25 new free templates in the coming month.</p>
            </div>
            </body>
```

Comment: Post your HTML code, please.

Comment: You can see the html now at the bottom, I added it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have a reset for your stylesheet?

```
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
  }
```

Even though you have a `margin:0` and `padding:0` for your div, it doesn't apply to the `p` or `h2` inside the `div`, so you have spaces.

Comment: no need to set the `margin:0` for all the elements, just set it for the `h2` as mentioned in the last sentence of yours.

Comment: @ King King, yes but that is a standard CSS to avoid such issue for the rest of his project.

Comment: It solves the OP's issue, but it may not explain to the OP's problem **clearly and exactly**.

Comment: The actual cause of the problem is the so-called **margin collapsing**, in this case the margin-collapsing happens between the child (the `h2`) and the parent (the `div`). Because the `div` does not have a top border, the margin of the `h2` will collapse with the margin of the `div` so that the maximum margin will become the margin of the parent `div`, in this case it's the margin of the `h2`. Here is the demo demonstrating it http://jsfiddle.net/viphalongpro/yEWBM/10/ If we specify the border for the parent `div`, there won't be margin-collapsing in this case.

Comment: Thanks to both for answering my question, your answers are better together- an intro, then a better theoretical explanation.

Comment: What I still don't get is why when I make it inline-block there is no margin collapsing?

Comment: @PetarDrianov margin collapsing happens only between block elements. It's some kind of standard specification, I've not even read that specification but you can search for more, there are a lot things to read.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Kingking, have a good day. Yes of course there is plenty of stuff to read- I understand from all that that inline-block is like a word or a letter. There is no space between inline-block and a block, but there is space between two inline-blocks. http://www.broken-links.com/2013/03/25/removing-the-whitespace-from-inline-block-elements/